# An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7, iis-6

I am frustrated by this Error: Please can help any one 
Thanks in advance ..
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'Login' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\accourtorder\424abf7c\95498d0a\assembly\dl3\168b9913\3bb51503_3619d101\App_Web_pswroej2.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\accourtorder\424abf7c\95498d0a\assembly\dl3\6b6d36c7\39b69e02_3619d101\App_Web_udswj3gx.DLL'

Source Error:

Line 146:
Line 147:    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()]
Line 148:    public class login_aspx : global::Login, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler {
Line 149:
Line 150:        private static System.Reflection.MethodInfo @__PageInspector_SetTraceDataMethod = global::ASP.login_aspx.@__PageInspector_LoadHelper("SetTraceData");

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\accourtorder\424abf7c\95498d0a\App_Web_login.aspx.cdcab7d2.pns3n113.0.cs    Line: 148

Answer (score 0):

Santosh,
Delete folder 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\accourtorder

Then restart iis

Then rebuild ur solution/project.

Should be good.